# How to create a lambda expression that filters from a list of items?

Tags: c#

I am using the Entity Framework, and have the following classes:

[image]

There is a search function which queries the database based upon some criteria, which is gathered in the SearchJSON object:

```
public class SearchJSON : ISearchObject
    {
        public List<String> sites { get; set; }
        public int minWage { get; set; }
        public int maxWage { get; set; }
        public List<String> countries { get; set; }
        public int minRating { get; set; }
        public int maxRating { get; set; }

    }
```

For now, I've managed to filter the results by HourWageMin and HourWageMax, but I would like to filter on countries and skills aswell. This is my query so far:

```
var query =
db.Freelancers.Where(x => x.HourWageMin >= data.minWage && x.HourWageMax <= data.maxWage).ToList();
```

I get the skills from the `List<String> skills` and countries from `List<String> countries`,
how do i add this to the lambda expression? The fields on the Skills and Countries objects are called Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should rename the Countries navigation property on Freelancers to Country to avoid confusion as it is a 0 or 1 to many relationship. I assume it's intended that a Freelancer can't have more than one country.

To filter on country is easy:

```
var query = db.Freelancers.Where(x => x.Country != null && x.Country.Name == "France");
```

To filter based on whether a freelancer has a specific skill:

```
var query = db.Freelancers.Where(x => x.Skills.Any(s => s.Name == "Artist"));
```

You can also chain Where methods together instead using using && over and over to make it more readable:

```
var query = db.Freelancers.Where(x => x.HourWageMin >= data.minWage)
                          .Where(x => x.HourWageMax <= data.maxWage)
                          .Where(x => x.Country != null && x.Country.Name == "France")
                          .Where(x => x.Skills.Any(s => s.Name == "Artist"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Any and Contains:

```
var query = db.Freelancers.Where(
    x => x.HourWageMin >= data.minWage &&
    x.HourWageMax <= data.maxWage &&
    x.skills.Any(s => data.countries.Contains(s.Name)) &&
    x.countries.Any(c => data.skills.Contains(c.Name))
).ToList();
```